# Can JUJU provide bare metal OS provisioning through iPXE or UEFI?

Tags: juju

I have a repository of OS ISO images. And I have VMWare hardware boxes. Can JUJU provide hardware what I require and then install OS from my list of ISO?

Comment: I have a repository of OS ISO images. And I have VMWare hardware boxes. Can JUJU provide hardware what I require and then install OS from my list of ISO?

Comment: Juju is an orchestration framework, you can use MAAS for that purpose (not sure about VMware). Ask it on MAAS (#maas) and Juju (#juju) IRC channels for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Juju is an orchestration framework, you can probably use [MAAS](http://maas.io) for that purpose which is a bare metal provisioning tool (not sure about provisioning VMware boxes). MAAS irc channel (#maas) can better clarify you about this.

Comment: thank you so much. :) what i was also looking for is we have only the machines without any OS. Is there any tool can do installation of any OS in those machines through PXE or UEFI ?

Comment: I think MAAS is your way to go, here you can find the docs to getting started: https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/. MAAS natively support Ubuntu and CentOS installation (no need to add repositories for these) while you can add other OS repositories (or a custom OS repo) as well.